# Rails outputting ActiveModel results to browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason, my rails app (the first one I'm tackling) is outputting ActiveModel query results to the browser with (apparently) no instruction from me. It happens in my View, whenever I `end` out of a loop to display said query results, which were generated in my Controller.

Here is a screenshot of my browser
[image]

And here is a screenshot of the code in my View which displays it
[image]

Lastly, here's a screenshot of the DOM which shows the output right before the closing ul, which is where <% end %> resides

[image]

Could anyone possibly tell me why Rails is sending the output in screenshot 1 to my browser? It is happening in other Views, too.

Comment: Don't post images unnecessarily. Instead post the code or errors you found.

Comment: I believe screenshots in this context were much clearer than pasting code out of context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in this line

```
<%= @themes.each do |t| %>
```

Correct:

```
<% @themes.each do |t| %>
```